# No module named 'asgiref.base_layer'

Tags: python, django, django-channels

When starting my server (python manage.py run server) I get the following error.

File "/Users/thomasallen/PycharmProjects/Channels_and_Signals/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asgi_redis/core.py", line 19, in 
from asgiref.base_layer import BaseChannelLayer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'asgiref.base_layer'

The offending line 19 in .../core.py is

```
from asgiref.base_layer import BaseChannelLayer
```

The packages I have installed are:
Django 3.2.4
channels 3.0.3
channels-redid 3.2.0
aspired 3.3.4
asgi-redis 1.1.0

I'm not sure where the mismatch is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `asgi_redis` 1.1.0 depends on an old version of `asgiref` (listed without an upper bound as `asgiref>=1.0.0` in their setup.py) which used to have this code. But you have a more recent version installed because Django depends on `asgiref >= 3.3.2`.

You shouldn't have both `asgi_redis` and `channels_redis` installed, they are different versions of the same package. See note in the [channels_redis git repo](https://github.com/django/channels_redis):

> Note: Prior versions of this package were called `asgi_redis` and are still available under PyPI as that name if you need them for Channels 1.x projects. This package is for Channels 2 projects only.

Your solution is to not use `asgi_redis` and use `channels_redis` instead.